# How to display y Axis on the right side on Graph

Tags: macos, core-plot

I want to implement a candlestick graph using core-plot. I have a little problem with yAxis. I'd like to display the yAxix on the right like this examples:

[image: example 1]
http://www.schaefferresearch.com/images/schaeffersu/tutorials/charts/candlestick.gif

[image: example 2]
http://www.mafiaforex.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/candlestick.gif

How?!

Looking at the examples I tried to change yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal with no result.

Thank you for your help!

Bye

G.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

```
yAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:0.0];
yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble("some number on X axis");
```

should work.

Comment: Also, the axis position will not move, only the labeling will be moved as you pinch or pan gesture occurred.

Comment: You only need one of those two lines. If you use the constraint, the axis will stay on the right side if you scroll the graph while the orthogonal coordinate makes it always cross at the same position on the x-axis.